# Why doesn't my mouse work when my computer is woken by keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, mouse, sleep

Whenever I wake the computer by the keyboard, the cursor doesn't move, and the mouse buttons don't work... But when I wake up computer by mouse move or click, all works correctly!

This doesn't *always* happen, but it does happen *very often*.  I've tried to replicate this under both Windows Vista and Windows 7 - and got the same result in both.

Just for reference, my mouse is a Microsoft 8000 Mouse (bluetooth).

Any ideas what could be the reason?  Thank you!

Comment: Can i ask where the devices are plugged into the machine at?  We had something simliar at my work place, basically they were plugged in to the monitor thus allowing wake up but would not for some reaosn repower the kb/mouse.

Comment: Bluetooth dongle is plugged into computer case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never really gotten on with bluetooth mice, does the mouse come back to life if you restart the bluetooth support service from start run services.msc

This should help identify whether it's a USB issue or a Bluetooth one.

Comment: Sounds like something good to try. Didn't know that there was a service to restart. Might be hard to do with only a keyboard, though.

Comment: You could to start run cmd (using windows key to get start menu) then type "net stop bthserv" then after it's stopped "net start bthserv"

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem years ago - it was a simple fix for me. I enabled 'USB Legacy Support" in the BIOS - it fixed it straight away!

Comment: That didn't help me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following?

> Go to Device Manager - under Blootooth
>   radios click Blootooth devices and
>   then open POWER MANAGEMENT where
>   deactivate "Allow the computer to turn
>   off this device to save power"-button.

Or is that already deactivated?

Comment: No "Power Management" is available there. Anyway, my mouse always can wake computer. But mouse doesn't work sometimes _after_ computer is woken.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have changed your default power plans, you may reset them back to their default settings by entering in cmd.exe "powercfg -restoredefaultschemes" and press Enter.
2. Is the mouse connected via USB?
   In at least one case I know, the only solution was to get a USB to PS2 adapter and plug the mouse into the PS2 port instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes guys. It seems to be a problem of not plugging the receiver directly into the PC without extension. Then the power management tab appears, and you can wake up the pC. Curious

Comment: Could you please clarify this a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 7 on a Dell and accidentally got a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard (instead of wireless) a Dell OPU235. Had to keep re-connecting after re-plugging my wired mouse keyboard on start-up. I went to the Control Panel and to Devices and then Power Options. I went to the USB Power and Disabled power-off to the USB on shut-down. Looks like this fixed the problem for me.